# HTTP query parameters regular expression

Tags: regex

Probably a minor one for the pros...

I want to detect a string of query parameters like:

```
var1=val1&var2=val2&...
```

I tried:

```
((.*)?(#[\w\-]+)?$&*)*
```

which is fine except it also matches

```
var1=val1&
```

which I don't want.

---

EDIT:

Tried also this:

```
(.*)=(.*)&*
```

is it a good solution?

Comment: Can you provide some examples of input data and expected results ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^([^=]+=[^&]*&)*([^=]+=[^&]*)$
```

Here, following matches one key-value pair.

```
[^=]+=[^&]*
```

So, zero or more key-value pairs each ending with `&`:

```
([^=]+=[^&]*&)*
```

And, one key-value pair at the end with no following `&`:

```
([^=]+=[^&]*)
```

#### [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/w0gbTm/2)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following,

```
(?:&?[^=&]*=[^=&]*)+
```

You can test it from [here](https://regex101.com/r/gZ5oVh/1) as well as its description.

---

> Tried also this:
>
> ```
> (.*)=(.*)&*
> ```
>
> is it a good solution?

No. What about the input string is something like `var1=val1&var2=val2&...sdsad3423--**909` ?